# How does rule-of-zero affect shared libraries with hidden visibility?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, rule-of-zero

NOTE: The question is at the bottom.

I'm trying to understand the problems that can occur if using rule-of-zero with shared libraries and derived types.

In the demonstration below, `DerivedType` is compiled with rule-of-zero or not depending on a preprocessor define. The script then demonstrates differences that arise, namely that if `DerivedType` has a key method defined in the cpp file, the vtable is emitted only in the shared library, whereas if there is no key method, the vtable is emitted in each consuming TU.

baselib.h:

```
#ifndef BASELIB_H
#define BASELIB_H

#ifdef BUILD_BASE_LIB
#define BASELIB_EXPORTS __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#else
#define BASELIB_EXPORTS
#endif

#include <memory>

class BASELIB_EXPORTS BaseType
{
public:
    BaseType() = default;
    virtual ~BaseType();
    BaseType(BaseType const&) = default;
    BaseType(BaseType &&) = default;
    BaseType& operator=(BaseType const&) = default;
    BaseType& operator=(BaseType &&) = default;
};

class BASELIB_EXPORTS DerivedType : public BaseType
{
public:
#ifdef DERIVED_RULE_OF_FIVE
    DerivedType() = default;
    ~DerivedType() override;
    DerivedType(DerivedType const&) = default;
    DerivedType(DerivedType &&) = default;
    DerivedType& operator=(DerivedType const&) = default;
    DerivedType& operator=(DerivedType &&) = default;
#endif

#ifdef DERIVED_TYPE_EXPLICIT_KEY
    virtual void key();
#endif
};

BASELIB_EXPORTS std::unique_ptr<BaseType> makeBaseType();

#endif
```

baselib.cpp

```
#include "baselib.h"

#include <iostream>

BaseType::~BaseType() = default;

#ifdef DERIVED_RULE_OF_FIVE
DerivedType::~DerivedType() = default;
#endif

#ifdef DERIVED_TYPE_EXPLICIT_KEY
void DerivedType::key() {}
#endif

std::unique_ptr<BaseType> makeBaseType()
{
    std::cout << "BASE LIB  " << &typeid(DerivedType) << "\n";
    return std::make_unique<DerivedType>();
}
```

otherlib.h:

```
#ifndef OTHERLIB_H
#define OTHERLIB_H

#ifdef BUILD_OTHER_LIB
#define OTHERLIB_EXPORTS __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#else
#define OTHERLIB_EXPORTS
#endif

#include "baselib.h"

class OTHERLIB_EXPORTS OtherDerivedType : public DerivedType
{
public:
    OtherDerivedType() = default;
    virtual ~OtherDerivedType();
    OtherDerivedType(OtherDerivedType const&) = default;
    OtherDerivedType(OtherDerivedType &&) = default;
    OtherDerivedType& operator=(OtherDerivedType const&) = default;
    OtherDerivedType& operator=(OtherDerivedType &&) = default;

    std::unique_ptr<DerivedType> getDerivedType();
};

#endif
```

otherlib.cpp

```
#include "otherlib.h"

#include "baselib.h"

#include <iostream>

OtherDerivedType::~OtherDerivedType() = default;

std::unique_ptr<DerivedType> OtherDerivedType::getDerivedType()
{
    std::cout << "OTHER LIB " << &typeid(DerivedType) << "\n";
    auto bt = makeBaseType().release();
    return std::unique_ptr<DerivedType>(dynamic_cast<DerivedType*>(bt));
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "otherlib.h"
#include "baselib.h"

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "MAIN      " << &typeid(DerivedType) << "\n";

    OtherDerivedType odt;
    auto dt = odt.getDerivedType();
    std::cout << "DT " << dt.get() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

```
#!/bin/bash

$COMPILER_DRIVER -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fPIC -DBUILD_BASE_LIB -o baselib1.o -c baselib.cpp
$COMPILER_DRIVER -shared -Wl,--no-undefined -o baselib1.so baselib1.o

$COMPILER_DRIVER -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fPIC -DBUILD_OTHER_LIB -o otherlib1.o -c otherlib.cpp
$COMPILER_DRIVER -shared -Wl,--no-undefined -o otherlib1.so otherlib1.o baselib1.so

$COMPILER_DRIVER -o main1.o -c main.cpp
$COMPILER_DRIVER -o def_rule_zero_without_key main1.o otherlib1.so baselib1.so

$COMPILER_DRIVER -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fPIC -DBUILD_BASE_LIB -DDERIVED_TYPE_EXPLICIT_KEY -o baselib2.o -c baselib.cpp
$COMPILER_DRIVER -shared -Wl,--no-undefined -o baselib2.so baselib2.o

$COMPILER_DRIVER -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fPIC -DBUILD_OTHER_LIB -DDERIVED_TYPE_EXPLICIT_KEY -o otherlib2.o -c otherlib.cpp
$COMPILER_DRIVER -shared -Wl,--no-undefined -o otherlib2.so otherlib2.o baselib2.so

$COMPILER_DRIVER -o main2.o -c main.cpp
$COMPILER_DRIVER -o def_rule_zero_with_explicit_key main2.o otherlib2.so baselib2.so

$COMPILER_DRIVER -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fPIC -DBUILD_BASE_LIB -DDERIVED_RULE_OF_FIVE -DDERIVED_TYPE_EXPLICIT_KEY -o baselib3.o -c baselib.cpp
$COMPILER_DRIVER -shared -Wl,--no-undefined -o baselib3.so baselib3.o

$COMPILER_DRIVER -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fPIC -DBUILD_OTHER_LIB -DDERIVED_RULE_OF_FIVE -DDERIVED_TYPE_EXPLICIT_KEY -o otherlib3.o -c otherlib.cpp
$COMPILER_DRIVER -shared -Wl,--no-undefined -o otherlib3.so otherlib3.o baselib3.so

$COMPILER_DRIVER -o main3.o -c main.cpp
$COMPILER_DRIVER -o def_rule_five_explicit_key main3.o otherlib3.so baselib3.so

echo
echo "Runtime demonstration of difference:"

echo
echo "The typeid is different when using rule of zero without a key method"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./def_rule_zero_without_key

echo
echo "The typeid is the same with a non-dtor explicit key and a defaulted inline dtor"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./def_rule_zero_with_explicit_key

echo
echo "The typeid is the same when using rule of FIVE/SIX and an explicit key"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./def_rule_five_explicit_key

echo
echo "Static demonstration of difference (nm -o):"

echo
echo "DerivedType vtable is emitted in consumer when using rule of zero"
nm -o otherlib1.o  | c++filt | grep vtable
echo
echo "DerivedType IS STILL visible (but externally defined) when using rule of zero with an explicit key"
nm -o otherlib2.o  | c++filt | grep vtable
echo
echo "DerivedType not visible with an explicit dtor and another virtual"
nm -o otherlib3.o  | c++filt | grep vtable

echo
echo "Static demonstration of difference (readelf -a):"

echo
echo "DerivedType vtable is emitted in consumer when using rule of zero"
readelf -a otherlib1.o  | c++filt | grep vtable
echo
echo "DerivedType vtable still emitted when using a defaulted destructor and an explicit key, but is NOTYPE GLOBAL DEFAULT and UND instead of OBJECT WEAK HIDDEN"
readelf -a otherlib2.o  | c++filt | grep vtable
echo
echo "DerivedType vtable is not emitted if the destructor is out of line"
readelf -a otherlib3.o  | c++filt | grep vtable

echo
echo
echo "In otherlib1, the vtable is present but HIDDEN (Is this STV_HIDDEN?)"
```

output with g++:

```
Runtime demonstration of difference:

The typeid is different when using rule of zero without a key method
MAIN      0x5580b2787d30
OTHER LIB 0x7f26b67f4dc8
BASE LIB  0x5580b2787d30
DT 0x559e26cc52c0

The typeid is the same with a non-dtor explicit key and a defaulted inline dtor
MAIN      0x55696d0f4d30
OTHER LIB 0x55696d0f4d30
BASE LIB  0x55696d0f4d30
DT 0x559e26cc52c0

The typeid is the same when using rule of FIVE/SIX and an explicit key
MAIN      0x5619fc118d30
OTHER LIB 0x5619fc118d30
BASE LIB  0x5619fc118d30
DT 0x559e26cc52c0

Static demonstration of difference (nm -o):

DerivedType vtable is emitted in consumer when using rule of zero
otherlib1.o:0000000000000000 V vtable for DerivedType
otherlib1.o:0000000000000000 V vtable for OtherDerivedType
otherlib1.o:                 U vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info

DerivedType IS STILL visible (but externally defined) when using rule of zero with an explicit key
otherlib2.o:                 U vtable for DerivedType
otherlib2.o:0000000000000000 V vtable for OtherDerivedType
otherlib2.o:                 U vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info

DerivedType not visible with an explicit dtor and another virtual
otherlib3.o:0000000000000000 V vtable for OtherDerivedType
otherlib3.o:                 U vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info

Static demonstration of difference (readelf -a):

DerivedType vtable is emitted in consumer when using rule of zero
COMDAT group section [   35] `.group' [vtable for OtherDerivedType] contains 2 sections:
COMDAT group section [   36] `.group' [vtable for DerivedType] contains 2 sections:
000000000013  00770000002a R_X86_64_REX_GOTP 0000000000000000 vtable for OtherDerivedType - 4
000000000013  007000000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 vtable for DerivedType + c
   112: 0000000000000000    32 OBJECT  WEAK   HIDDEN   112 vtable for DerivedType
   119: 0000000000000000    32 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT  110 vtable for OtherDerivedType

DerivedType vtable still emitted when using a defaulted destructor and an explicit key, but is NOTYPE GLOBAL DEFAULT and UND instead of OBJECT WEAK HIDDEN
COMDAT group section [   35] `.group' [vtable for OtherDerivedType] contains 2 sections:
000000000013  00710000002a R_X86_64_REX_GOTP 0000000000000000 vtable for OtherDerivedType - 4
000000000013  006b0000002a R_X86_64_REX_GOTP 0000000000000000 vtable for DerivedType - 4
   107: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND vtable for DerivedType
   113: 0000000000000000    40 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT  107 vtable for OtherDerivedType

DerivedType vtable is not emitted if the destructor is out of line
COMDAT group section [   34] `.group' [vtable for OtherDerivedType] contains 2 sections:
000000000013  00670000002a R_X86_64_REX_GOTP 0000000000000000 vtable for OtherDerivedType - 4
   103: 0000000000000000    40 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT  102 vtable for OtherDerivedType


In otherlib1, the vtable is present but HIDDEN (Is this STV_HIDDEN?)
```

NOTE: HERE IS THE QUESTION:

Is there some mode by which `dynamic_cast` will fail, or some other failure mode which might be hard to debug if vtables are emitted in multiple TUs and shared libraries?

Comment: There's no issue with multiple translation units. The problem arises from the use of shared libraries, the mechanics of which are not defined (and barely even anticipated) by the C++ standard. As such, any answer is going to be specific to an ABI and even to a compiler.

Comment: Also, FWIW, this is only tangentially related to the "rule of zero". The destructor only happens to trigger the issue in this example. The existence of any other out-of-line virtual function would have the same effect.

Comment: If you add a check to see if the `dynamic_cast<>` in your test code succeeded or not (i.e. `std::cout << dt.get() << "\n`, what do you get?

Comment: @Sneftel My question doesn't ask what the c++ standard has to say. Bringing that in just introduces confusion, so please refrain.

I also extended the example to show that a non-dtor key method is not "the same", but may be "equivalent". I don't know.

Comment: Note that the question is at the bottom. It says: "Is there some mode by which `dynamic_cast` will fail"

Comment: It's certainly not showing the same thing, as `key()` is not declared as virtual in `BaseType`. My point about the standard, though, is that since it defines Standard C++, it doesn't make sense to ask "How can I do this in C++". Shared libraries do not exist in "C++". At best, it makes sense to ask something like "how do I do this in Clang on Linux."